# Swiffy container/JavaScript only works within HTML body of Joomla template

Tags: javascript, svg, joomla, html5-canvas, google-swiffy

I made a template which uses a svg canvas animation/swiffy container in the header. It all works fine until I put it in a Joomla tremplate.

I had similar problems with JavaScript inside a Joomla template but could resolve these by adjusting the JavaScript. Is there something similar here that I should do?

The JavaScript of the swiffy container apparently needs to be somewhere after the container div of the swiffy svg animation.

Is the problem in the code? Can I fix the code so it works also in the heading with a [$.noConflict();] code or something like that?

The other problems with JavaScript in a Joomla template could be solved by putting the scripts before the [`<jdoc:include type="head" />`] but in this case it had to be after the swiffy container div.

Here is the JavaScript;

```
        <script>

      var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('swiffycontainer'),
          swiffyobject, {  });

      stage.start();
    </script>
```

And here is the Joomla template in action with the nonworking swiffy container containing the svg canvas animation [Joomla template in action](http://www.drummersantana.nl/rieon/)

Comment: Thanks Peter O, for your cleaning up :-) English isn't my native language.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the JavaScript can be outside the body element, just as long it is under/after the swiffy/svg code.

So placing the script in the header solved my problem.

Comment: If you make this explanation a little more detailed you could accept your own answer.